# Recomposition Error in live edit Andriod jetpack

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-edittext, android-jetpack-compose

this is my main Activity , I am getting recomposition error on change the Text value on android emulator

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Text(text = "hi99")

        }
    }
}
```

The error is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wmVA.png)

```
Error was captured in composition while live edit was enabled.
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find 'Text-nZBYWUE(Ljava/lang/String;Landroidx/compose/ui/Modifier;JJLandroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontStyle;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontWeight;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontFamily;JLandroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextDecoration;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextAlign;JIZIILkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;III)V' in androidx/compose/material3/TextKt
                                                                                                    Found:
                                                                                                        'class androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle[class androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle, interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2, interface androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int]void
                                                                                                        'class androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.Text--4IGK_g[class androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString, interface androidx.compose.ui.Modifier, long, long, class androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle, class androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight, class androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily, long, class androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration, class androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign, long, int, boolean, int, interface java.util.Map, interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, class androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle, interface androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int, int, int]void
                                                                                                        'class androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.Text--4IGK_g[class java.lang.String, interface androidx.compose.ui.Modifier, long, long, class androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle, class androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight, class androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily, long, class androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration, class androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign, long, int, boolean, int, int, interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, class androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle, interface androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int, int, int]void
                                                                                                        'class androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.Text-IbK3jfQ[class androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString, interface androidx.compose.ui.Modifier, long, long, class androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle, class androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight, class androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily, long, class androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration, class androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign, long, int, boolean, int, int, interface java.util.Map, interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, class androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle, interface androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int, int, int]void
                                                                                                        'class androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.Text-fLXpl1I[class java.lang.String, interface androidx.compose.ui.Modifier, long, long, class androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle, class androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight, class androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily, long, class androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration, class androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign, long, int, boolean, int, interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, class androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle, interface androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int, int, int]void
                                                                                                        'class androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.getLocalTextStyle[]class androidx.compose.runtime.ProvidableCompositionLocal
                                                                                                        'class java.lang.Object.identityHashCode[class java.lang.Object]int
                                                                                                        'class java.lang.Object.identityHashCodeNative[class java.lang.Object]int
                                                                                                        'class java.lang.Object.internalClone[]class java.lang.Object
                                                                                                        'class java.lang.Object.clone[]class java.lang.Object
                                                                                                        'class java.lang.Object.equals[class java.lang.Object]boolean
                                                                                                        .....
```

I tried rebuidling it

Comment: I tried this locally and it worked for me but the exception looks legitimate and could indicate a problem in Live Edit. Please report this to Android Studio with the version of Android Studio and the configuration you used to construct the emulator.